# What is the authenticity of the hadith that says "women were created for nothing but evil"?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> “I think that women were created for nothing but evil.” (Hanbal, Musnad, volume 6, p. 86)

Is the above report authentically attributed to the Prophet SAW?

Comment: Fwiw, I can't really find this Hadith with the given reference in the places I looked. That could just be because the one who referenced it used a different edition of the book.

Comment: Where did you find this quote and reference?

Comment: It's from a word document

Comment: @Afiq  they took it out of context and its also da’eef

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hadith is as follows:

> قالت عائشة: دخل علي رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بسرف وقد نفست وأنا منكسة، فقال لي: " أنفست؟ " فقلت: نعم، يا رسول الله، ولا أحسب النساء خلقن إلا للشر، فقال: " لا، ولكنه شيء ابتلي به نساء بني آدم
>
> Aisha said: The Messenger of Allah ﷺ entered upon me when we were at Sarif and I was menstruating and I was depressed.
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ asked: "Are you in menses?"
>
> I replied: "Yes, and I think that women are only created for evil."
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said: "No, rather this is a thing with which Allah has tested the daughters of Adam."
>
> <sup>— [Musnad Ahmad](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/20764) - [Vol 6 Page 86](https://ia600204.us.archive.org/18/items/waq3014/06_3019.pdf)</sup>

The context of this hadith is the same as [Bukhari 294](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:294), [Muslim 1211](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1211i), [Abu Dawud 1782](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1782), [Nasai 290](https://sunnah.com/nasai:290) etc.

Things to consider:

- The part you have quoted was not said by the Prophet ﷺ, but rather by Aisha, and the prophet ﷺ negated it.
- This hadith with this specific wording is weak because its chain is severed as Abu Ubaid did not meet Aisha.

Comment: Wouldn't a better translation be "a thing which Allah has tested the daughters of Adam with"?

Comment: Jazak Allah khayr